# what kind of qr-like code is divided into 4 quarters

Tags: qr-code, barcode, datamatrix

I was wondering what kind of QR code does not sport squares in the corners and is divided into 4 quarters by a solid black line? I would like to replicate this, since I think they look more professional than the variety I have seen before, but I cannot find out what kind of code it would be?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) has descriptions of all the different QR codes, none of them look like this.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a code? (As Barmar mentions, it's not a QR code; it must be some sort of other 2D matrix code.)

Comment: As an added note, I wouldn't worry about how professional it looks.  QR is common on many professional products.  It's better to consider how your user will interact with it.  Most consumers are familiar with QR codes being used to give them additional information such as internet links or text information, and cell phone generally read them fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's a data matrix 2D barcode.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode

It only looks divided into 4 blocks when you get above a certain size (such as 20x20 shown below)

http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/images/datamatrix-structure-details.png

This article talks more about these blocks (or more officially, 'Data Regions' or 'sub matrices').  See page 12 for a table of common sizes and data region breakdowns:

http://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_DataMatrix_Introduction_and_technical_overview.pdf

> The matrix symbol (square or rectangle) will be composed of several
>   areas of data (or: Data Regions), which together encode the data.